# Importing a git repo from AWS CodeCommit to BitBucket from web interface?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, repository, bitbucket, aws-codecommit

I have a git repo on AWS CodeCommit, and I want to import it using the BitBucket web interface. I used the https access keys but it's giving me (No repository exists at that URL.), although it has not authentication problem.

fatal: unable to access '*https://repoUR*L': The requested URL returned error: 403
11:55:32 Remote Git clone failed: : Command failed. Return value: 128

Comment: If you simply pushed that repo to BitBucket, it would have been done faster than you can finish writing the above question. :-)

Comment: I did so, but it added the master branch only, not the whole repo. I used git remote, and then git push -u <name> master

Comment: That's because you only pushed `master`. You have to push each branch. Or, if you have many branches, `git push --all` and `git push --tags`.